# Can Tasks be filtered by Iteration in LookbackAPI?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Here is a store that returns 0 tasks in iteration, even though there are tasks on user stories in iteration 12345. If I use 'HierarchicalRequirement' instead of 'Task' in '_TypeHierarchy', stories are returned. I also tried adding 'Iteration' to the fetch, but it did not help

```
var snapshotStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
                autoLoad:true,
                fetch    : ['Name','_TypeHierarchy'],
                filters  : [{
                    property : '__At',
                    value    : 'current'
                },
                {
                    property : '_TypeHierarchy',
                    value    : 'Task'
                },
                {
                    property : 'Iteration',
                    value    : 12345
                }
                ],
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Rally LBAPI Documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual/unavailablefields)

> The following fields are not available through the Rally Lookback API.
>
> - Big/rich text fields (Description, Notes, etc.)
> - Attachments
> - Weblink fields
> - LastBuild, LastRun, LastVerdict on TestCases
> - Iteration or Release on Tasks
> - Attributes for all unsupported entities (Workspace, Iteration, Release, Requirement), e.g. Name, EndDate, StartDate on iterations